# How to use GeometryReader without it filling the View

Tags: layout, swiftui, geometryreader

This is the layout I'm aiming for.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct TestView: View {
        
    let text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(self.text)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TestView(text: "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla")
                .frame(width: 250)
                .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

[image]

But I also want to use the `GeometryReader` and when I put the `Text` inside the `GeometryReader` it will take up the full height.

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct TestView: View {
        
    let text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { reader in
            Text(self.text)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TestView(text: "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla")
                .frame(width: 250)
                .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

[image]

How can I get around this?

Comment: It is not a bug - it is an intended feature.

Comment: I know but how can I use geometryreader to achieve the layout at the top?

Comment: using vstack inside geometry and Spacer() after text?

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING ⚠️ : This is when Geomtery reader couldn't help with me with geometry and I started to bang my head against the wall**

Here's what you can do:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var text =  "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla"
    var width : CGFloat = 250

    var height: CGFloat {
        var size : CGFloat
        let chars = self.width / 14  // assuming width of 1 character is 14 which is the case by default for Text view
        let lines = CGFloat(text.count) / chars
        size = CGFloat(14 * (lines + 1))
        return size
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TestView(text: text)
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
            .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Set the height of the TestView manually by using height as a computed property.

[image: screenshot]

A background story on how I estimated default font height

Press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>
Use the pointer and find the difference between the relative y positions